# How to scrape Javascript element from HTML source code?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I scrape the javascript element from http://www.asfinag.at/home? I think that the javascript element starts from `items:`  in the source code of the page.

My current code looks like this:

```py
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.asfinag.at/home'

req = urllib.request.Request (url)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
f = opener.open (req)
soup = BeautifulSoup (f)
tmp = soup.find_all(id="at-asfinag-pvis-pages-map-LayerPage-0")
print (tmp)
```

I don't know how to proceed. I basically need to scrape fields such as `fahrtrichtung` and `meldequelle`.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's a Javascript program. JSON happens be designed to be like the syntax of literal objects in Javascript, but there's much more in there than just the object. There's no general mechanism for this.

Comment: thx for the fast response, altough the answer means a lot of work for me :(